# C#: Deleting all characters between two Delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, split

got a little Stringcutting problem. I got a string like this:

```
@VAR;Variable=Deteministic;Value=mostly;Note=Unless Slave is already in use;Op==;@ENDVAR;
```

the Note is not neccessary for me, so I want to cut out everything that begins with Note until the next Semicolon. The Replace-Method would be nice, but I dont know how to get the Chars after Note away.

I tried something like this:

```
 int index1 = rs.IndexOf("Note=");
 int index2 = rs.IndexOf(';', index1+1);
 rs = rs.Remove(index1, index2);
```

I thought this should be sufficient, but it fails if there is no note and my program pops out an error. Regex would be an option, but I cant think of one the fits in here.

Please note, the example was just a sample. I dont know how the inputstring looks like. One line can contain two Notes and another line can have none. Please consider this in your answers.

Comment: There is a quiet nice online regex engine to test your regular expressions against your own data: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
Try this pattern `(Note=[^;]+;)` and the engines explains to you what it does when you hover your mouse over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regex can indeed help here:

```
rs = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=;)Note=.*?;", "");
```

Let me explain the more obscure parts of it:

- `(?<=;)` makes sure `Note` is preceded by a semicolon. That semicolon is, however, not part of the replacement. (That's a [positive look-behind assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs)).
- `.*?;` matches all characters until the semicolon, but *non-greedy*. This ensures that `Note=A;x=B;` is only matched until the *first* semicolon and `x=B` is retained.

Comment: Why would you choose for a positive look-behind on the `;`? The asker of the question states: `I dont know how the inputstring looks like`. So how can you be sure the string never starts with a `Note`?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: Basically, I'd want to avoid `@VAR;ThisIsNotANote=...;x=B` to be matched. If the string can start with `Note` (it does not look like it, it looks like it starts with `@VAR`), one could use `((?<=;)|^)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Heinzi, great work. Works perfect and you made the right assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other regex answers to this post will indeed work, but it might be appropriate with a non-regex answer just to show that there are other tools available than the hammer :)

I'm assuming you just want to ignore all entries starting with `Note=`

```
string input = "@VAR;Variable=Deteministic;Value=mostly;Note=Unless Slave is already in use;Op==;@ENDVAR;";

// Entries will contain all entries except those starting with 'Note='
string[] entries = input.Split(';').Where(s => !s.StartsWith("Note=")).ToArray();
// If you want to, you can put it all back together without the Note entries
string output = String.Join(";", entries);

// Ouput: @VAR;Variable=Deteministic;Value=mostly;Op==;@ENDVAR;
Console.WriteLine(output);

// Output:
// @VAR
// Variable=Deteministic
// Value=mostly
// Op==
// @ENDVAR
foreach (var entry in entries)
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

Comment: I accepted the first answer of Heinzi, but this looks also good. Thanks for the work and the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this ?

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Note.*?;");      
var ouput = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `StringBuilder`. It is much more efficient that `string`. Then if you want to preserve you original idea:

```
 int index1 = -1;

while( (index1 = sb.IndexOf("Note=")) >=0)
{
   int index2 = rs.IndexOf(';', index1+1);
   rs = rs.Remove(index1, index2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

```
Note[^;]+;?
```

Something a bit like:

```
rs = Regex.Replace(rs, @"\bNote[^;]+;?", "");
```

`\b` matches a word boundary.

`[^;]` matches any character which is not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
int index1 = rs.IndexOf(";Note=");
while(index1 > -1)
{
    int index2 = rs.IndexOf(';', index1 + 1);
    rs = rs.Remove(index1, index2);
    index1 = rs.IndexOf(";Note=");
}
```

Comment: What if there are several "Note=" ?

Comment: @Alireza Use a `while((index1 = rs.IndexOf("Note=")) != -1)` would be possible. But regex is probably more elegant here.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Right, but this answer is flawed by its own

Comment: @Alireza you're right. edited and used a wile to account for multiple `Note` elements